# Angular Upgrade: Can't find stylesheet to import

Tags: angular, sass-loader

I'm having trouble upgrading an Angular project from version 14 to 15.

Specifically I think it has to do with the momentum-ui/core library.

To recreate the error

1. Create a new Angular 15 project with `npx @angular/cli@15 new name-of-project`
2. Install [momentum-ui/core](https://github.com/momentum-design/momentum-ui/tree/master/core) `npm install @momentum-ui/core`
3. Follow the instructions in the link above ie. add the following to src/styles.scss

```
$brand-font-folder: "@momentum-ui/core/fonts";
$icon-font-path: "@momentum-ui/icons/fonts";
$images-path: "@momentum-ui/core/images";
@import "@momentum-ui/core/scss/momentum-ui.scss";
```

4. `npm run start`

I get this error:

```
  │ @import '~@momentum-ui/icons/scss/momentum-ui-icons';
  │         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  ╵
  @momentum-ui\core\scss\momentum-ui.scss 5:9  @import
  src\styles.scss 5:9                          root stylesheet

./src/styles.scss?ngGlobalStyle - Error: Module build failed (from ./node_modules/mini-css-extract-plugin/dist/loader.js):
HookWebpackError: Module build failed (from ./node_modules/sass-loader/dist/cjs.js):
SassError: Can't find stylesheet to import.
  ╷
5 │ @import '~@momentum-ui/icons/scss/momentum-ui-icons';
  │         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  ╵
  @momentum-ui\core\scss\momentum-ui.scss 5:9  @import
  src\styles.scss 5:9                          root stylesheet
```

There are similar issues  which I tried, like removing `~`, adding `"stylePreprocessorOptions": { "includePaths": [ "./node_modules" ] }` to angular.json and using `@use` instead but to no avail.

I'm guessing the `@momentum-ui/core` needs to remove the use of ~ but are there any work arounds in the mean time as a consumer of that library.

The error doesn't occur on StackBlitz, I'm guessing they compile their scss differently??

Answer (score 1):

For icon usage you don't need core. Just install `@momentum-ui/icons`

Import `momentum-ui-icons.scss` in your styles (scss):

```
@import "@momentum-ui/icons/scss/momentum-ui-icons.scss";
```

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-z9j2fv?file=src%2Fmain.ts,src%2Fglobal_styles.scss,src%2Findex.html

If it doesn't work, pls provide your node and sass version.

Answer (score 0):

After looking into it, it's just because Angular 15 has entirely removed support for tildes in scss. The package I'm using needs to be updated.